# How to display option result in JavaScript on the same page

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS, still playing with the basics. I have a problem with displaying result on the same page in `<div>` once the selection is made. Result is displayed on the new page for some reason.

### JS code:

```
<script>
  function changeFunc(choice){
    var x = choice.value;
    document.write("You choose " + x + " option");
  }
</script>
```

### HTML:

```
<div id="test">
  <h2>Choose one</h2>
  <select onchange="changeFunc(this)">
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
   <option>4</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Instead of using document.write use node.innerHTML..like this

```
 <head>
   <script>    
      function changeFunc(choice){
        var x = choice.value;
       //document.write("You choose " + x + " option");
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You choose " + x + " option";
    }
   </script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div id="test">
     <h2>Choose one</h2>
     <select onchange="changeFunc(this)">
       <option>1</option>
       <option>2</option>
       <option>3</option>
       <option>4</option>
     </select>
  </div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

The write() method is mostly used for testing: If it is used after an HTML document is fully loaded, it will delete all existing HTML.

Note: When this method is not used for testing, it is often used to write some text to an output stream opened by the document.open() method.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use document.write. Instead, create a div in html and write the result to that div.

HTML:

```
<div id='result'></div>
```

Javascript:

```
function changeFunc(choice)
{
   var x = choice.value;
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You choose " + x + " option";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can define a new DIV and then update same by innerHTML.

here is a working example:

```js
 var displayDiv = document.getElementById('displayResult');

changeFunc =   function(choice){
    var x = choice.value;
    displayDiv.innerHTML = "you choose" + x;

  }
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <h2>Choose one</h2>
  <select onchange="changeFunc(this)">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="displayResult"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u1rfwcf1/3/